# precision and recall for clustering of text documents using java?

Tags: java, data-mining, text-mining

how to calculate precision and recall for clustering of text documents using java? (documents are clustered using k-means)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

```
double precision = tp / (tp + fp);
double recall = tp / (tp + fn);
```